# Generating Elevation Profile

Tags: python, profile, gdal, elevation

### Approach

I have an array of points [[lon1, lat1], [lon2, lat2], ..., [lonN, latN]]. I am looping through the points and generating elevation on each point as:

```
for point in points:
    ...
    alt = ds_band.ReadAsArray(px, py, 1, 1)
    # push the alt to an array
```

where,
*ds_band* is the raster band
*px* is the x_offset
*py* is the y_offset

### Problem

**Small DSM file (~80 MB) Vs Large DSM file (~5 GB)**

Fetching the altitude information from the small DSM file is fairly quick. However, fetching altitude information from large DSM file takes longer time. 
For the approximately same amount of points (33370), it takes 1.983694553 seconds in small DSM file. But in large DSM file, it takes 9.140556812 seconds.

*The time is for fetching the elevations only. It does not include other operations like opening the DSM file.*

### Question

Is there a better way of fetching the elevations of multiple points than what I am doing? Is there a way to optimize the ReadAsArray?

P.S. New to Python/GDAL. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn’t mind waiting 10 seconds for it to load. But maybe you vectorise it.

Comment: @FChm I also wouldn't mind but the client does. :D. By vectorizing you mean vectorizing the raster file? Can you elaborate? Sorry new to the field. Still learning

Comment: The 9.34 seconds includes opening the file, or just fetching the elevations? Depending on that the solution may not be optimizing ReadAsArray.

Comment: Hi @lusitanica, 9.34 seconds includes time to open the file and time to generate points. But those times are very small and if we only calculate the time to fetch elevation, then it comes around 9.14 Seconds. Apologies. I should have specified that in the question. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do, except to make sure your input file is easy to process.

Most geospatial formats are not optimized for random access.

If you need fast random access:

- Make sure you are using an uncompressed input file - most formats have some form of (eventually optional) compression, check the GDAL driver page for information on how to disable compression for your file format, uncompressed GeoTIFF is a very good choice for this
- If your points tend to be close together, make sure that the input file is tiled and they fit in one tile
- If you are always using the same file over and over again, you can lock it in memory with `vmtouch`